# One slow Cassandra node kills whole cluster performance

Tags: performance, cassandra

We lost one of our Cassandra nodes recently and tried to replace it (using standard [node replace procedure](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_replace_node_t.html)). But unfortunately, after finishing bootstrap node becoming very slow (because of ongoing compactions, which is kinda logical). But the problem that after that whole cluster read performance becoming very slow.
[image]
We have replication factor = 3 and LOCAL_QUORUM consistency, and I thought that [rapid read protection](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/rapid-read-protection-in-cassandra-2-0-2) should protect us from that - but it didn't happening. Does someone have idea why?
Apache Cassandra 2.1.15, Java datastax driver, RF=3, LOCAL_QUORUM.

Comment: If compaction consuming resources is really your problem, try throttling compaction throughput: `nodetool setcompactionthroughput 1`.  Also check the value of `concurrent_compactors`.  If you're not giving that a value it's picking a default (based on # of disks and cores) which may not work for your node.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron, will check that. But I mostly concerned with non-working rapid read protection.